# update iframe form action url when user hit the URL with specific parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Here is Code Example

Page URL is : http://example1.com?id=1

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>main page</h1>
    <iframe src="http://example2.com">
      <form id="test" action="http://example3.com?id=1">
        ...
      </form>
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now my Question is How to update the iframe Form Action URL when USER Hit Page URL with different parameter value.(Example, if User hit URL with parameter id=2 then form action URL should be changed to id=2, i.e action="http://example3.com?id=2",

How to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can get paramet in jquey and then you can change action attribute of form.

Comment: Passing the `id` parameter onto the iframe `src`. So `<iframe src="http://example2.com?id=2">`. Then you can use javascript to extract the URL parameter and change the `action` attribute. Alternatively you can change the hash on the iframe `src`. That way you can use the `hashchange` event to dynamically change the form `action` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can try with following code

Add below code in iframe. And call it on document ready.

```
  function getQueries () {
  // This function return value is assigned to QueryString!
  var query_string = {};
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        // If first entry with this name
    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
      query_string[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        // If second entry with this name
    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
      var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]],decodeURIComponent(pair[1]) ];
      query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
        // If third or later entry with this name
    } else {
      query_string[pair[0]].push(decodeURIComponent(pair[1]));
    }
  }
  return query_string;
};
```

This will return object which will include parameters which are passed in url.

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var _curQueries = getQueries();
    if(_curQueries["id"] !== undefined)
    {
        var myForm = document.getElementById('test');
        myForm.action = 'http://example3.com?id='+_curQueries["id"];
    }

    /*
    var _params = "";
    var _counter = 0, _length = _curQueries.length;
    for(var i in _curQueries)
    {
        _params += i+"="+_curQueries[i];
        _counter++;
        if(_counter < _length)
        {
          _params += "&";
        }
    }
    var myForm = document.getElementById('test');
    myForm.action = 'http://example3.com?'+_param;
    */
});
```

Comment: i can't add this code in iframe code it's an external URL,

Comment: i am not getting.. you are loading example2.com in iFrame and example2.com is not your code right ?? also 

you want to change form action to change with respective to parameter passed ??  and form is part of that iFrame only right ??

Comment: Yes, exactly, i need to pass the parameter value to the form action URL.

Comment: That won't be possible as you don't have access over example2.com.